# How can I do the configuration of I/O cards with the xhw file in EcoStruxre Control Expert?

Tags: plc

I have this hardware configuration of an extension rack for a M580 PLC projet using EcoStruxure Control Expert

[image]

I export the.XHW file by following the procedure below:
https://www.se.com/uk/en/faqs/FAQ000256454/

And I am trying to rename the DD1602 card using the file, however, when I rename the card as a show in the next image (selected in green), and re-change the file to the .XHW extension, when I re-import it into Control Expert, I get an error saying: unknown fatal exception, even though the only change I've made is to the name of the card.

[image]

I know I can rename IODDTs instances manually in Control Expert, but in fact I'm trying to automate the process of renaming IODDTs because I have a lot of IODDTs to rename, which is why I thought of using the XHW file.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do?

Thanks in advance